# cordova orientation lock vertical flip not working

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to lock orientation for cordova android app to landscape using

```
<preference name="Orientation" value="landscape" />
```

This works fine it loads app in landscape view. But when I flip the emulator vertically(upside down - 180degree) the screen remains fixed and does flips the view vertically. I want to show in landscape mode only even if user rotates the device to 180 degrees.

Using cordova-android: 7.0.0

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to this, without using any plugin. We can put configuration in config.xml to modify AndroidManifest.xml at build time.

Put the following in config.xml

```
<edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" target="/manifest/application/activity[@android:name='MainActivity']" mode="merge">
   <activity android:name="MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="userLandscape" />
</edit-config>
```

Also add following in the `<widget>` tag of config.xml

```
xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Following are possible values for the `screenOrientation` field

```
screenOrientation (attr) enum [behind=3, fullSensor=10, fullUser=13,
landscape=0, locked=14, nosensor=5, portrait=1, reverseLandscape=8, 
reversePortrait=9, sensor=4, sensorLandscape=6, sensorPortrait=7, 
unspecified=4294967295, user=2, userLandscape=11, userPortrait=12]
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use this for unlock(both mode) for

```
 screen.orientation.unlock();
```

and use screen lock portrait mode

```
screen.orientation.lock('portrait');
```

Comment: Yes, plugin required

Comment: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation/

Comment: Ok. Actually I did not want to use a separate plugin for this functionality. My answer solves the issue without any plugin.

Comment: This answer also does not work at app start time, so if you have a splash screen, it may be upside down.